# cannnot install ROS in Ubuntu 14.10

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I built catkin from source, but I cannot.

```
 -- catkin 0.6.15
-- Searching for Poco library...
CMake Error at /home/chibi314/ros_catkin_ws/install_isolated/share/cmake_modules/cmake/Modules/FindPoco.cmake:186 (MESSAGE):
  Poco was not found.  Set the Poco_INCLUDE_DIR cmake cache entry to the
  top-level directory containing the poco include directories.  E.g
  /usr/local/include/ or c:\poco\include\poco-1.3.2
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:7 (find_package)


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/home/chibi314/ros_catkin_ws/build_isolated/class_loader/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
<== Failed to process package 'class_loader':
  Command '['/home/chibi314/ros_catkin_ws/install_isolated/env.sh', 'cmake', '/home/chibi314/ros_catkin_ws/src/class_loader', '-DCATKIN_DEVEL_PREFIX=/home/chibi314/ros_catkin_ws/devel_isolated/class_loader', '-DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/home/chibi314/ros_catkin_ws/install_isolated', '-DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release', '-G', 'Unix Makefiles']' returned non-zero exit status 1

Reproduce this error by running:
==> cd /home/chibi314/ros_catkin_ws/build_isolated/class_loader && /home/chibi314/ros_catkin_ws/install_isolated/env.sh cmake /home/chibi314/ros_catkin_ws/src/class_loader -DCATKIN_DEVEL_PREFIX=/home/chibi314/ros_catkin_ws/devel_isolated/class_loader -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/home/chibi314/ros_catkin_ws/install_isolated -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release -G 'Unix Makefiles'

Command failed, exiting.
```

I don't know how to install "poco". Please tell me how to install poco.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/219090/cannnot-install-ros-in-ubuntu-14.10/) by [chibi314](https://answers.ros.org/users/24470/chibi314/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2015-10-13

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

poco is a system dependency.

The [source installation instructions](http://wiki.ros.org/jade/Installation/Source) should help you install all your system dependencies such as poco.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2015-10-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

sudo apt-get install libpoco-dev

Mark

---

Originally posted by [MarkyMark2012](https://answers.ros.org/users/2193/markymark2012/) with karma: 1834 on 2015-10-14

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1